# my query won't work with dates

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I would like to return records from the latest date in the past ... but it's not working

```
SELECT * 
FROM EVENTS WHERE 1 
AND discipline_id
IN ( 2 ) 
AND event_start_date < NOW( ) 
ORDER BY DATE( event_start_date ) ASC


event_start_date is of type date in the database ..
```

Comment: What is not working? and why do you use DATE() in event_start_date? And if you want the latest it should be DESC, not ASC

Comment: it's not working either ...

Comment: What is the nature of the "not working"? Are you getting wrong results? Are you getting errors? That query should get you the events for discipline_id =2 sorted by event_start_date ASC, without any changes, if event_start_date is actually of date datatype in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ordering by just `event_start_date`

```
SELECT * 
FROM EVENTS
WHERE discipline_id
IN ( 2 ) 
AND event_start_date < NOW( ) 
ORDER BY event_start_date DESC
```

Also I'm not sure why you are doing `WHERE 1`, as that will always return true.

Comment: What isn't working about it...? If you simply copy/pasted, then I've fixed it, since I happened to have left the `WHERE 1` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you want to select latest records from db, go with following type of a query

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE_NAME 
WHERE DATE IN (MAX(DATE))
```

Answer (score 0):

With almost 1/2 hour gone by and no repsonse / feedback, take your query one step at a time... and build on it.

One step at a time... First, simplify to just the one ID and ALL dates but apply the order by...

```
SELECT *
   FROM EVENTS 
   WHERE discipline_id = 2 
   ORDER BY event_start_date DESC
```

Now, look at the results... if it doesn't return anything, you have either no data, or a bigger problems elsewhere.  If that DOES work, then since the event date is in descending order, you should be able to see if there ARE ANY records that are before the NOW() criteria you were attempting.  Then just add the NOW() criteria

```
SELECT *
   FROM EVENTS 
   WHERE discipline_id = 2 
      AND event_start_date < NOW()
   ORDER BY event_start_date DESC
```

If no records, then so be it, but there is nothing complex about this query in the slightest...  Yes, this data is in most recent date at the top of the list (vs oldest now at the bottom).  If you want only the MOST RECENT event prior to now(), then just apply a limit 1 to get THE most recent

```
SELECT *
   FROM EVENTS 
   WHERE discipline_id = 2 
      AND event_start_date < NOW()
   ORDER BY event_start_date DESC
   LIMIT 1
```